# Android convert milliseconds to hours

Tags: java, android, time, calendar, parseint

I have milliseconds in String and i want to get hour and minutes from it.

This is my `code` :

```
String ms = "1425652847915";
int t = Integer.parseInt(ms);

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, t);

int  h = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int  m = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

But i got this `error` :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: unable to parse '1425652847915' as integer

Any suggestion?

Comment: @WarrenFaith being nice to a beginner programmer must be really hard

Comment: @quixotrykd he was nice imo

Comment: Really???? I can reading the error message! i khow what it's from!!! but i can't parse big int! thanks for downvoting!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously `1425652847915` is greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE) but you still need to set the time for `Calendar`

```
long t = Long.parseLong("1425652847915");
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(t);
```